# Symfony - saving array to database

Tags: arrays, json, database, api, symfony

I wrote a function where I get array of marks that i need to post to my database..

[image]

My function stores it in a filed row like:
[image]

And I need to pull just one per column individually like:[image]

Here is my api call..

```
public function generate(Map $seatMap)
{
    $layout = $seatMap->getSeatLayout();

    $seats = [];

    $layoutArray = json_decode($layout, true);

    $columns = range('A', 'Z');

    foreach($layoutArray as $index => $result)
    {
        $columnLetter = $columns[$index];
        $letters = str_split($result);

        $letterIndex =  1;
        foreach($letters as $letterIndex => $letter) {
            switch($letter) {
                case 'e':
                    $seats[] = $columnLetter . $letterIndex;
                    $letterIndex++;

            }
        }
    }

    foreach($seats as $seat => $result) {
        $result = new Seat();
        $result->setName(json_encode($seats));

        $this->em->persist($result);
        $this->em->flush();
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions? 
I think that problem is in the part where I need to store it to database..

Comment: What you mean by "pull just one per column individually"?

Comment: To insert a new row for A1, new row for A2 etc..

Comment: So you want ti create multiple instances of `Seat`. Why would you try to encode it to json and pass to single `Seat` instance?

Comment: Yes. I stucked with it so I didn't know what else to try. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your issue is here:

```
foreach($seats as $seat => $result) {
    $result = new Seat();
    $result->setName(json_encode($seats));

    $this->em->persist($result);
    $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

You're indeed creating new `Seat` instance for every seat, but in this line:

```
$result->setName(json_encode($seats));
```

you still assign all (encoded) seats to every instance of `Seat`. What you want is to assign only the seat from current loop iteration, which is represented by `$result` variable.

So try with:

```
$result->setName($result);
```

You do not need `json_encode` here too.

Comment: I tried. It saves it like this ----name: ["A0","A1", "A2"] and I want for every letter to be inserted I a new row..

Comment: This is what you're getting when you're encoding all seats  with json. I don't think you've tried it, because it's impossible to get the same result, when trying two different things. You cannot get `["A0","A1", "A2"]` if you never pass all of them to `Seat::setName`. You must have messed something up.

Answer (score 0):

If your array is like you say it it then try this

```
foreach($seats as $seat) {
    $result = new Seat();
    $result->setName($seat);

    $this->em->persist($result);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```